# Can I write chat application with asynchronous processing in Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, servlets

Does Servlet 3.0 specification with implementation in Tomcat 7 allow to write chat application without additional reverse-ajax library? What is asynchronous processing for?

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous processing allows you to continue in processing of a task while 'waiting' for result of another task - you do not have to wait for return of a method call - look at **java.util.concurrent.Future** for the starters.

I don't think Tomcat alone will do the job, you still need some counterpart in browser - if you want to try something new for this look at **web sockets**.